# What is the ordinary differential equation for double exponential summation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ordinary differential equation (ODE)

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = a y$$

its general solution is $y = c e^{a x}$, where $c$ is a constant. If we know

$$y = c_{1} e^{a_{1} x} + c_{2} e^{a_{2} x}$$

what is the corresponding ordinary differential equation for this solution?

Comment: If there is two linelely independent solution which is solution of second order  linear homogeneous differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y''(x) + ay'(x) + by(x) = 0$, then it is well known that the general solution is:

$$c_1 e^{\alpha x} + c_2 e^{\beta x}$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of the quadratic $x^2+ax + b = 0$.

This result can be obtained by letting $y = e^{rx}$, finding $y'(x)$ and $y''(x)$, and then substituting those values into the differential equation.

So the original problem has been transformed into: given the roots of a quadratic equation, how can I find the original quadratic? This is easy if you just expand $(x + \alpha)(x + \beta) = 0$, or use Vieta's formulas.

Answer (score 2):

General method:  From an expression with two parameters $c_1, c_2$, to find the second-order DE with that solution.

Step 1, solve for $c_1$
Step 2, differentiate to eliminate $c_1$
Step 3, solve for $c_2$
Step 4, differentiate to eliminate $c_2$.
The result is an equation involving $y, y', y''$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=c_{1}e^{a_{1}x}+c_{2}e^{a_{2}x}$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$(r-a_1)(r-a_2)=0$$
$$r^2-(a_1+a_2)r+a_1a_2=0$$
Then you deduce the differential equation:
$$y''-(a_1+a_2)y'+a_1a_2y=0$$